# Can track belong to the application and not individual users?

Tags: soundcloud

My application isn't going to be revolved around soundcloud users, I will be using it for its nice api that is provided to stream audio. I also want to use the javascript upload feature but that seems to be out of the question too.

The record widget should be able to upload the audio to your server so that you can upload the audio not as an individual user.

I still haven't been able to get my app to work without using their authentication window.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly everything you do with the SoundCloud API must be done on behalf of a SoundCloud account. You can only use the SoundCloud API to stream content from or upload content to a SoundCloud account.

If you'd like to have SoundCloud functionality in your app, I'd recommend allowing users to connect their SoundCloud accounts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I will be going with another service.

Answer (score 0):

"Authenticating without the SoundCloud Connect Screen", from the API docs: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#user-credentials

With this method you can log in as a user in the code. Since every app must be registered to a user anyway, you can make a new username to register the app, and log in with that one.

Comment: If I login say using the python script, could I use that token for the purpose of using the javascript recorder?

Comment: If your recorder can save a file somewhere the script can access it, you should be able to upload it. (I've successfully done something similar.) I don't know whether the API allows streaming *to* SoundCloud, though.

Comment: the javascript recorder is made by soundclound. Its really nice and I want to use it. That is what this discussion is about. But as mentioned above I maybe able login with python then use that token so that the javascript recorder doesn't try to long them in again.

Comment: Ahh, I see – so from the SoundCloud API's point of view, you'd have a logged-in user upload a sound to the app owner's account, yes? That might work - you'd have to authenticate with both accounts, I don't know how the API would handle that. Good luck!