# soundcloud authentication for server-side code (no app!)

Tags: api, authentication, soundcloud

I would like my server-side code to upload tracks to soundcloud in its own name, then later it will retrieve comments, favourites and listener counts.  I do not want to do this on behalf of an app user - for **there is no app**!  Previous questions here on stackoverflow§ (there is no "me too" button) and the API docs seem to suggest I cannot do this.  Am I correct?

§ [Can track belong to the application and not individual users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725669/can-track-belong-to-the-application-and-not-individual-users)

Comment: your server-side code would be “the app”

Answer (score 1):

This is called "Authenticating without the SoundCloud Connect Screen" in the API docs:
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#user-credentials

An "app" in this case is a program that wants to access the Soundcloud API. You register them here:
http://soundcloud.com/you/apps/

Normally you would make a unique username, and register the app to that user. Then, the code logs in as that user to authenticate.